# Xamarin.Android Preview Problem in VS for Mac

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, preview, visual-studio-mac, android-9.0-pie

When I targeted **Android 9.0 (Pie)** in Android part of Xamarin.Forms app the **Preview of UI** produces an error and show nothing.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Open a new Xamarin.Forms App in VS For Mac then update all of the Android Packages. After that, target your app to Android 9.0 as I described above. Finally you should run one time your app in an Android Emulator and you will see the error in Preview Tool in **VS for Mac**. The problem isn't in app. App is running well but I can't see preview of the UI to change things immediately.

**(Error: android/view/View.OnUnhandledKeyEventListener)**

Comment: the previewer sucks and only causes strange errors and never showed my anything. use [Hotrelead](https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/HotReload) instead.

Comment: I tried the Hot Reload and it is impressive. Thanks for your suggestion man. But I am still curious about my problem :)

Comment: I can understand that you are curious but for your sake, I'd suggest give up Visual  Studio built-in Previewer. Yout view is now pretty simple and you can't get the previewer working. Imagine what will happen when you have a complex UI. Better not waste time & use 3rd party tools. You can try either HotReload (as @magicandre1981 suggested) or LiveXAML. Anything is better than the built-in one

Comment: Thank you man. You are right. I am going to use 3rd party tools.